# compiler cannot deduce overload of std::max

Tags: c++, stl, std-function, overload-resolution

With my compiler

```
typedef const double&(*fT)(const double&, const double&);
typedef std::function<const double&(const double&, const double&)> std_func;

fT f1 = std::max<double>;                            //(1)
std_func f2 = static_cast<fT>(std::max<double>);     //(2)
std_func f3 = f1;                                    //(3)
```

(1, 2, 3) work but

```
auto f4 = std::max<double>;                          //(4)
std_func f5 = std::max<double>;                      //(5)
```

(4, 5) don't. The compiler complains about its incapability to choose the overload for case 5.

Is this behavior normal?

What is the most portable and correct way to write it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Slava I'm trying to fix the compiling errors of an old code base on one more compiler. The old code was (5). I fixed it by writing (3). Thx for your commen, an answer is welcome :-)

Comment: I think then you should rephrase your question as how to make (5) compile and what variants you tried, as it is written it is not clear at all

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two possible overloads of instantiation of `std::max<double>`: `std::max(double, double)` and `std::max(std::initializer_list<double>)`. Because of that, versions 4 and 5 fail, since it can't figure out which overload matches.

Cases 1, 2 and 3 succeed because of the special rules - when taking an address of overload function, type of the result is used to select the proper overload.

Comment: Thank you SergeyA for your answer. So, as far as I understand, I can live happy with solution 3.

Comment: @jimifiki all of them are feasible, depending on your preference. 3 works too.